# How to apply the "Extract Method" refactoring to a piece of code

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring, .net-2.0

We have a legacy application that has a 1200 lines long method (the run method of a thread). The method is mostly a single while(true) containing a long sequence of sentences.

The following C# region is present around 50 times in the method:

```
#region Cancel pending
     if (backgroundWorkerPrincipal.CancellationPending)
    {
        if (CanCancelThread)
        {
            ev.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
    }
#endregion
```

I'm wondering the correct (if possible) way to extract this region to a new method.

As I said, that fragment (Region) appears around 50 times within the method. Please note the return within the #region (which would exit the while).

So the method has the following structure:

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs ev)

    while(true) {

        ...

        #region Cancel pending
             if (backgroundWorkerPrincipal.CancellationPending)
            {
                if (CanCancelThread)
                {
                    ev.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
        #endregion

        ...

        #region Cancel pending
             if (backgroundWorkerPrincipal.CancellationPending)
            {
                if (CanCancelThread)
                {
                    ev.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
        #endregion

                ...

        #region Cancel pending
             if (backgroundWorkerPrincipal.CancellationPending)
            {
                if (CanCancelThread)
                {
                    ev.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
        #endregion

                ...

        #region Cancel pending
             if (backgroundWorkerPrincipal.CancellationPending)
            {
                if (CanCancelThread)
                {
                    ev.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
        #endregion

        ...

        #region Cancel pending
             if (backgroundWorkerPrincipal.CancellationPending)
            {
                if (CanCancelThread)
                {
                    ev.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
        #endregion

        .
        .
        .

    }

}
```

Comment: Should this actually be tagged as java?

Comment: @nbrooks nice catch.

Comment: In .net 4.5, this `BackgroundWorker` can be replaced with `Task`, `async` and `await`. Give it a try.

Comment: @LeiYang sadly this is an old application and we need it to keep runing on .net 2.0

Comment: I guess most of them can simply be deleted.

Comment: Between each of those regions are heavy database operations and Thread.sleep calls...

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say that there's a *correct* way to refactor it, just some funky ways to do it that will work, including extracting it to a method that returns true/false whether or not to execute a control statement.  You'd still have to repeat it 50 times, so there's not much to gain in doing that.

I'm not going to recommend refactoring that block of code at all.  Instead, I'm going to suggest that you **refactor the code around it**.  Refactoring an adjacent piece of code can sometimes reveal patterns that you were unable to identify before.

Start by extracting methods for each of those "..." blocks.  What you have now is a pattern of "calling a method, then bailing if cancellation is pending."  By converting those methods to delegates, they become data elements and you can loop on them.

Let's assume for a minute that the extracted methods have the same signature.  Declare an array of delegate instances, execute them in a loop, and check for pending cancellation at the end of each iteration.  Since you have a return instead of a break, you don't have to do anything extra to get out of the inner loop.

```
var extractedMethods = new Func<State, DoWorkEventArgs, State>[]
{
    DoStep1,
    DoStep2,
    DoStep3,
    // ...
};

while (true)
{
    foreach (Func<State, DoWorKEventArgs, State> fn in extractedMethods)
    {
        state = fn(state, ev);

        if (backgroundWorkerPrincipal.CancellationPending && CanCancelThread)
        {
            ev.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

"Calling a method and then bailing if cancellation is pending" is now separate from the list of methods it's going to call and you only have one cancellation check to maintain.  The list of methods is established up front and then fed into that block.  You could take the extra step of extracting the while loop to its own method and then passing the list of delegates to it.  On the other hand, that might be taking it too far for your needs.

If the extracted methods have different signatures, it's not as simple but you do have some options.  You could adjust the methods to take the same parameters and have them ignore the ones they don't use.  Too many parameters, though, and the maintainability can start to get away from you, especially if you have to adjust 50 different methods.  If you foresee the need for more parameter variation in the future, this probably won't be a good option.

Another option is to use lambdas with a relatively simple signature and take advantage of closures to abstract away the differences.

```
var extractedMethods = new Func<State, DoWorKEventArgs, State>[]
{
    (st, ev) => RunStep1(st, ev /*, parameters specific to RunStep1 */),
    (st, ev) => RunStep2(st, ev /*, parameters specific to RunStep2 */),
    (st, ev) => RunStep3(st, ev /*, parameters specific to RunStep3 */),
    // ...
};
```